# White border around Label with an image?

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, tkinter

I put some image in a tkinter widget, with the classical:

```
logo=PhotoImage(file="C:\Users\name\Desktop\image.gif")
immglab1=Label(image=logo)
immglab1.image=logo
immglab1.pack(anchor=N)
```

[image]

The problem is that when I set the widget background color (#1A1A1A) same as image background color is appeared a white frame around the `image.gif` and I can't understand why.

Some suggestions?

Comment: Please show the code that *doesn't* work as expected. Code that works fine doesn't help in finding the problem. Also, what exactly do you mean by "set the widget background color same as image background color is"? Please show example code and perhaps an example image. It helps a lot if people can replicate the problem you're experiencing.

Comment: there isn't  a code that doesnt't work.
there is something that shouldn't be there.
however, edited.

Comment: Call it what you want, but you have code that doesn't do what you want it to do. That should be the code that you post, not code that already does what you want it to. The edit you made does make the problem statement clearer, thanks for that.

Comment: @fhdrsdg: I think you are being too critical. The problem is not buggy code, the problem is a lack of understanding as to how to properly configure a widget. The code as posted is quite sufficient to duplicate this specific problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley To be honest, without the image I had no idea what the problem was he was talking about (we're not all as experienced with Tkinter as you are ;) ). If the image had been included from scratch I probably wouldn't have commented at all. In general though, I think that it just doesn't make sense to post code that works as expected, users should post the code that demonstrated the problem. In this case, the code that produces the window as shown in the image would have explained everything, whereas the code that's posted doesn't explain much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The white frame is the image border and/or highlight ring. You need to set the `borderwidth` and `highlightthickness` attributes to zero:

```
immglab1=Label(image=logo, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
```