# What causes this white border around tkinter label widgets?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a chess board and after creating Canvas widgets for each of the chess board pieces. I have put labels around the board however the show up with this weird white border than i have no idea how to remove.

```
def createGrid(self):
    colour = True
    self.grid_list = []
    for rows in range(8):
        label = Label(self.canvas, text='{}'.format(rows+1), bg='#727272', highlightthickness=0)
        label.grid(row=rows, column=0)
        row_list = []
        self.grid_list.append(row_list)
        colour = not colour
        for columns in range(8):
            label = Label(self.canvas, text='{}'.format(self.letters[columns]), bg='#727272',
                          fg='white', highlightthickness=0, height = 2)
            label.grid(row=8, column=columns+1)
            if colour:
                grid_piece = Canvas(self.canvas, width=self.size / 8, height=self.size / 8, bg=self.colour1,
                                    highlightthickness=0, highlightbackground='#727272')
                grid_piece.grid(row=rows, column=columns+1, padx = 0, pady = 0)
            else:
                grid_piece = Canvas(self.canvas, width=self.size / 8, height=self.size / 8, bg=self.colour2,
                                    highlightthickness = 0)
                grid_piece.grid(row=rows, column=columns+1)
            colour = not colour
            row_list.append(grid_piece)
```

Board with weird borders

[image]

Comment: That appears to be the border of `self.canvas` (which is not shown in the code you posted), being partially overlapped by the Labels.  I'm not sure why you even have a `self.canvas`, as nothing Canvas-like is being done with it - it might as well be a Frame.

Comment: Sounds related: [White border around Label with an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30457568/white-border-around-label-with-an-image)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough code in your question for others to run it, so I added my own and was able to reproduce the problem after a lot of trial and error. I think the border is being caused by not specify `borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0` everywhere it's needed, so I added it around the `Frame` subclass and the main `Canvas` it contains.

Here's the result:

[image: screenshot of script running with no white border shown]

And here's the code used:

```
from tkinter import *


class Foo(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(*args, bg='#727272', borderwidth=0,
                                  highlightthickness=0)
        self.pack()
        self.canvas = Canvas(self, borderwidth=0, bg='#727272', highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.letters = list('ABCDEFHI')
        self.size = 768
        self.colour1 = '#7C1900'
        self.colour2 = '#FFDFC4'

    def createGrid(self):
        colour = True
        self.grid_list = []
        for rows in range(8):
            label = Label(self.canvas, text='{}'.format(rows+1), bg='#727272',
                          highlightthickness=0)
            label.grid(row=rows, column=0)
            row_list = []
            self.grid_list.append(row_list)
            colour = not colour
            for columns in range(8):
                label = Label(self.canvas, text='{}'.format(self.letters[columns]),
                              bg='#727272', fg='white', highlightthickness=0, height=2)
                label.grid(row=8, column=columns+1)
                if colour:
                    grid_piece = Canvas(self.canvas, width=self.size / 8,
                                        height=self.size / 8, bg=self.colour1,
                                        highlightthickness=0,
                                        highlightbackground='#727272')
                    grid_piece.grid(row=rows, column=columns+1, padx=0, pady=0)
                else:
                    grid_piece = Canvas(self.canvas, width=self.size / 8,
                                        height=self.size / 8, bg=self.colour2,
                                        highlightthickness=0)
                    grid_piece.grid(row=rows, column=columns+1)
                colour = not colour
                row_list.append(grid_piece)

root = Tk()
foo = Foo()
foo.createGrid()
root.mainloop()
```